# Spring boot configure with two IP address

Tags: tomcat, endpoint, spring-websocket

I have a spring boot project and I need to configure it to cater requests from two IP addresses. My system has two NICs and two IPs.

I wish to configure it in such a way that -

- one nic serves requests for text web and
- other nic serves requests for streaming like binary websockets.

From application.yml I know I can use `server.host` and `server.port` to set an IP address. But I could not find a way to configure second IP into spring boot.

I've seen examples on internet using 'TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' for configuring different ports, but none using different ip addresses.

The main reason for such a single setup is that I can share the authentication information between the requests(from different IPs).

Really appreciate, if anyone can suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, I know that 3 years past. But I faced with the same issue now. Did you find the way to configure second IP in Spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

```
connector.setProperty("address","127.0.0.1");
```